# Spring Boot Security/LDAP direct bind with user credentials

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

Is there a way to authenticate a user with Spring Boot Security/LDAP using the credentials instead of first binding with some functional credentials and then trying to bind the user?

I want to not need to use `managerDn` and `managerPassword` like in:

```java
auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchBase("")
    .userSearchFilter("(samAccountName={0})")
    .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://<url>/<root>")
        .managerDn("functionUser")
        .managerPassword("password")
```

Comment: If the LDAP server you are using allows for anonymous access then no technical user is needed.

Answer (score 2):

In my application, I implemented a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate a user against my own database or a remote LDAP depending on a flag set in the user record.

To authenticate against the remote LDAP, I used the code below. It worked for me, perhaps, it will work for you too :).

```java
protected void validateCredentialsAgainstActiveDirectory(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
    try {
        LdapConfiguration config  = ...;
        
        /*
         * We will create a new LDAP connection on the fly each time an AD user logs in.
         * Hence we must disable caching properties to avoid NullPointerException later
         * in AbstractContextSource.getAuthenticatedEnv().
         * 
         */
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(config.getUrl());
        contextSource.setCacheEnvironmentProperties(false);
        
        // Authenticate the user against the pre-configured userDnTemplate
        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] { config.getUserDnTemplate() });
        bindAuthenticator.authenticate(authentication);
    
    } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
        // Catch downstream exception to return our own message
        throw new BadCredentialsException(SpringUtils.getMessage("security.login.error.bad-credentials"));
        
    }
}
```

FYI, `LdapConfiguration` is my own custom class for reading configurations from a `.yml` file. In this file, I configured the url and the DN template of the LDAP server as following. You need to change that to fit your environment.

```yml
url: ldap://10.10.10.231:10389/dc=mycompany,dc=com
userDnTemplate: uid={0},ou=people
```

Don't forget to import the necessary dependencies in your project too.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's actually not best practise to build the DN as this does not allow to have an arbitrary Directory Information Tree (DIT).

Best practice is to retrieve the entry DN for the consecutive BIND operation by a SEARCH operation.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr I imitated the implementation from Spring LDAP Authentication Provider :). I don't have enough experience with LDAP to evaluate whether the current working solution is the best one but it sure works. Do you mind providing an answer and show us the better way to do it with a SEARCH operation? I'd be very grateful for that.

Comment: it works as long as your DIT is really simple, here all the 'user' entries are below entry 'ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com' ... in real enterprises this is seldomly the case as the 'user' entries which should be authenticated are spread in different containers.  Hence you do a search using a unique attribute  - in AD this is typically 'samAccountName', but you can use any attribute this is guaranteed to be unique. Not every LDAP Directory Server allows to use the empty DN "" as a search base, hence the search base has to be provided by the LDAP administrator.

Comment: Very smart LDAP clients are querying  the so called 'rootDSE' to find out the capabilities of the LDAP server they are talking to.